# How to update javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a js object like

```
[{"name":"John","group":"t1..." .....}]
```

so to create new user from same t1, I loop through the obj using

```
var new_user;
for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
  if(users[i].group === 'group name goes here') {
    new_user = users[i];
    break;
  }
}
```

then is simply push it using `users.push(new_user);` then I try to change the just the name using

```
var l = users.length - 1; users[l].name = 'Jack';
```

it changes the name for the all the users.

```
[{"name":"Jack","group":"t1..." .....},{"name":"Jack","group":"t1..." .....}]
```

I know I am doing something wrong. I appreciate any help.

Comment: var l= users.length-1;

Comment: My bad i missed the -1. Sorry

Comment: Are you sure that all of the other elements had `name` other than `Jack` before you do `users[l].name = 'Jack'`?

Comment: @ekad i am sure all had different names.

Comment: It's not that you're doing anything wrong, but how JavaScript handles the values. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language for more details...

Comment: at the end you are changing all elements, when you do new_user = users[i]; you copy the ref

Comment: How about something like this - > http://jsfiddle.net/6whsLvuo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Haneev's answer gives the concept of why the `name` of all `users` elements was changed by your code. Below is a code example of how you copy `users[i]` using [slice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
var users = [{"name":"John","group":"t1"}];

var new_user;
for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
  if(users[i].group === 't1') {
    // make a copy of users[i] and assign to new_user
    new_user = users.slice(i);
    break;
  }
}

// add new_user to users
users.push(new_user);

var l = users.length - 1; 
users[l].name = 'Jack';

alert(users[0].name); // this will display John
alert(users[1].name); // this will display Jack
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hkLkkepo/

Answer (score 7):

Problem here is that you assign the a new variable name to an old object. That is a reference and not a copy of the object. `new_user = users[i]` creates an reference that `new_user` is linked to `users[i]`. You have to copy the `users[i]` object, in order to only change the `new_user`. Underscore has a copy/clone function that you can use.